# Cauchy's theorem spin-off

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, prime-numbers

In group theory we know from Cauchy's theorem that any finite group of order n has at least one subgroup of order p, if p|n.
How can we prove the following statement: "If G is a finite group of order n, p is a prime number and r a natural number so that p^r|n, then the group has at least one subgroup of order p^r."?

Comment: Have you seen Sylow's theorems?

Comment: Only heard of them, Tobias, they are not featured in my textbook. An introduction would be appreciated.

Comment: @user4773863 Is this an assigned problem? Proving this statement essentially amounts to proving (parts of) the Sylow theorems. What tools do you have available? Do you know about group actions?

Comment: Yes, i know about group actions, and no, this is not an assigned problem, but rather something that would make my assigned problem a lot easier.

Comment: [Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/555226/169852) is a reasonably elementary proof by induction. It just requires Cauchy's theorem and the class equation.